# How can I make an interval timer?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the bootstrap loading bar:

```
  <div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped active" id="loading" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="75" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%">
  </div>
  </div>
```

I'm trying to change the width of the bar every few seconds so it looks like the bar is making progress.

I have this but it's not working:

```
   setInterval(function () {
      var percentl = percentl + 5;
      document.getElementById("loading").style.width = percentl + "%";
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're declaring `var percentl` in the function block, so `percentl` is declared in the scope of the internal function only, each time the function is invoked the value of `percentl` is undefined and after setted to NaN (as RobG says in the comment). Try this:

```
var percentl = 0;
setInterval(function () {
  percentl = percentl + 5;
  document.getElementById("loading").style.width = percentl + "%";
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

1) percentl has a local scope in your function. You are redefininng it to the same value every time it is called.

set percentl with a global scope that can be accessed by your anonymous function every time it is called.

2) You are also calling setInterval only once. You should call it in a loop until you reach 100%. Something like:

```
var percentl = 0;


function increase(){

setInterval(function () {
      percentl = percentl + 5;
      document.getElementById("loading").style.width = percentl + "%";
      if(percentl < 100){
        increase();
      }
  }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: You're not updating the value of percentl, so the value is always 0.

Comment: Oops, skipped that after editing. Fixed, thanks (by the way, this is quick and dirty, but should get him going)

Answer (score 1):

```
var i = 0;
function increase(){
    setInterval(function () {
        document.getElementById("loading").style.width = i + "%";
        i++;
        increase();
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `(var i = 0; i <= 100; i=i+5)` if you want to step a little faster (and <= 100 to reach 100%)

Comment: That will very quickly set 100 functions to be called after 1 second, so they'll all run at about the same time and all have a closure to *i*, so they'll all get a value of 100% (the last value of i).